# Jenkins pipeline for multiple repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on micro-service base Jenkins pipeline. There is similar code pattern / structure in Bitbucket repository for Java and angular based code. Can I manage multiple repositories with single pipeline with dynamic approach which can provide filter option (like AJAX in java) in drop down  like I can get more than one repositories in drop down option and I can select any repository, based on this repository, I can get branches from this repository in next drop down and I can execute Jenkins pipeline.

Do we have any Jenkins plugin which can provides filter option for Bitbucket repositories in Jenkins.
Presently I am using Git parameter option in Jenkins pipeline (Build with parameter) and then created several pipelines.

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/ - might help you

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want a job in which you can select a repository and then select a branch from that repository and hit GO and build that branch of that repo?  If this is the case then the answer is no.

You would have one Job per repository, and if that job is a multibranch pipeline then you would be able to select the branch to build from there.

You can enable all the repos and branches to use the "same" pipeline that you then submit parameters to using a Shared Library